# Angular directive with a ng-switch containing an input: can it be done cleanly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

- **In brief**

I'm looking for a cleaner way to work around an issue that involves isolate scopes. I'm not sure there's a better workaround that what I have, but I hope so as I'm not too happy with it.

- **The demo**

[Demo on Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q5RWCLq9OOQMbIk1pymC?p=preview)
Contains both a directive that shows the problem, and another one with the dirty fix.
Change the values of the inputs and see it doesn't get propagated for one of them.

- **The story**

I wrote a directive that contains a `ng-switch`. The code is:

```
angular.module('core')
.directive('otherSearchField', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'otherSearchField.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      field: '=',
      placeholder: '@',
      condition: '@searchWhen'
    }
  };
});
```

Its template is:

```
<section ng-switch="condition">
  <div ng-switch-when="true">
    <input type="text" ng-model="field" placeholder="{{placeholder}}">
    <button ng-click="search()">Search</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-default>
    {{field}}
  </div>
</section>
```

I could rewrite it as a `ng-if`, but what matters really is that in both cases, **a new scope is created by ng-switch or ng-if**.

I use the directive this way:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <other-search-field field="query.city" placeholder="City" search-when="{{edition.city}}"></other-search-field>
</div>
```

- **The issue**

As you notice, in the directive template, we have an input bound to "field". That one is bound to the calling template via the `=` notation in the directive definition.
However, **because we're not using the object notation, entering something in the input modifies the `field` in the ng-switch's scope, but does not propagate out of it.**

- **A (dirty) solution**

My current solution is to use the object notation in the directive's template, which means I need to pass the containing object to the directive, and the name of the property I want to modify.

```
<section ng-switch="condition">
  <div ng-switch-when="true">
    <input type="text" ng-model="fieldParent[field]" placeholder="{{placeholder}}">
    <button ng-click="search()">Search</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-default>
    {{fieldParent[field]}}
  </div>
</section>
```

Usage:

```
<my-search-field field-parent="query" field="customer" placeholder="Customer" search-when="{{edition.customer}}"></my-search-field>
```

This works: I'm using the object notation so the changes on the input propagate all the way up (see on the Plunkr linked above).

- **So ?**

Hmm, I'm not too happy to pass an entire object when only one of its properties is needed though. Is there a better way ?

- **NB**

Note I could also, in this case, use multiple `ng-show` as they don't create their own scope. But I'm interested in the more general issue shown here, not in this specific case.

Thanks for reading all the way. Kudos to you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `otherSearchField.html` template, you can access the `$parent` `$scope`'s field property, thereby accessing the isolate scope that your directive `<other-search-field>` is using.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/4LBr0Xn6qLr1GAnrKlgC?p=preview)**

```
<section ng-switch="condition">
  <div ng-switch-when="true">
    <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.field" placeholder="{{placeholder}}">
    <button ng-click="search()">Search</button>
    <div>value in the template, in "switch": {{$parent.field}}</div>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-default>
    {{field}}
  </div>
</section>
<div>
  value in the template, out of "switch": {{field}}
</div>
```

Comment: Oh... so that is when using $parent makes sense. I always avoided it as if it didn't exist until now.